# How can I see the output of document.write while debugging?

Tags: javascript, firebug

I often need to step thought JS scripts in Firebug for debugging purposes. Often those script will use `document.write()` to generate new html content and while I can easily see the code lines that generate the code, I would very much like to see the the generated contents while debugging.

In other words, can I see the the output from `document.write` while debugging?

**UPDATE:**

To avoid misunderstandings, I need to clarify that I mean debugging and scrutinizing *other people's* scripts like banner scripts that very often use document.write to generate content. I have no control over their use of document.write, I just need to explore the output.

I would not use document.write myself.

Comment: Replace document.write with console.log()/console.debug()?

Comment: NB: `document.write` should be avoided. There are valid reasons to use it, but usually it's the wrong tool. Using DOM methods or at least `innerHTML` are usually the better choice.

Comment: I was probably not expressing myself clearly enough. See the clarified question.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to write to the Firebug console looks like this: console.log("hello world")

You can pass as many arguments as you want and they will be joined together in a row, like console.log(2,4,6,8,"foo",bar).

[Intro: Firebug and Logging](http://getfirebug.com/logging)
[API doc](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API)

Answer (score 0):

You could copy paste the code inside the document.write and paste it as a watch in your firebug window